# Why does `echo bash | bash` take an immediate exit?

Tags: shell-script, debugging

All of the following operations are no-effect operations:

```
echo bash | bash
echo dash | dash
echo "bash -c bash" | bash
echo "dash -c dash" | dash
```

Why? For the first line, for instance, I would assume that it would create a bash instance, and then *it* would create another bash instance waiting for input. But it does not wait for input; it exits. The parent bash also exits. So both bash instances exit and I'm back at whatever shell instance I launched these commands from. Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second bash instance *does* wait for input on its stdin (which is the same pipe the `bash` string was read from), but it only gets an EOF as soon as the `echo` process has exited and the writing end of the pipe has been closed.

You could try to give some input to the second bash, too:

```
(echo bash; echo echo hjello) | bash
hjello
```

Comment: Or `(echo bash; cat /dev/tty) | bash` will wait for input from the terminal. There won't be a prompt because the inner shell is not interactive.